# Can I use a custom allocator for std::array for secure cryptographic keys?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, cryptography, allocator

I know `std::array` is completely allocated in the stack, but this question is motivated by security concerns that require two things:

1. The data in `std::array` will be zerod or randomized on destruction
2. The data in `std::array` will be [locked](https://linux.die.net/man/2/mlock), such that it never goes to disk neither on crash or on swap memory

Usually, with `std::vector`, the solution is to create a [custom allocator](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/src/support/allocators/secure.h) that [does these things](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/src/support/lockedpool.cpp). However, for `std::array`, I don't see how to do this, and hence this question.

The best I could do is this:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t Size>
struct SecureArray : public std::array<T, Size>
{
    static_assert(std::is_pod<T>::value, "Only POD types allowed")
    static_assert(sizeof(T) == 1, "Only 1-byte types allowed")
    virtual ~SecureArray()
    {
        std::vector<uint8_t> d = RandomBytes(Size); // generates Size random bytes
        std::memcpy(this->data(), d.data(), Size);
    }
}
```

But this obviously lacks memory locking and complicates the performance scheme of `std::array` that is to be gained by using `std::array` in the first place.

Is there any better solution?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203977/discussion-on-question-by-the-quantum-physicist-can-i-use-a-custom-allocator-for).

Comment: Sorry, that was for the mods; the other was the mod that rejected the flag, not you. The only thing you can do is of course to indicate if the answers are correct or not, so I can assign the bounty to the best one. I can eval myself of course, but I'm not that great an expert. The reason for the bounty disappears anyway once it is assigned.

Comment: @Maarten-reinstateMonica Unfortunately none of the answers solve the problem in a clean way.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist What would it take to be considered a clean way? Could you try and make those requirements explicit? That helps thinking about a possible solution as well. I think I might know what you mean, but I also think you can probably be more precise.

Comment: @Maarten-reinstateMonica Using an allocator that we already have in some way. Rewriting stuff from scratch is a bad idea and will require hell of testing. That should be the last resort. The answers below are suggesting obvious solutions that I already mentioned I'm avoiding in the comments (before moving them to chat).

Comment: @Maarten ah, two answers were provided before another mod saw the flag, so it was rightfully declined now as it would put the two answers at a disadvantage.

Comment: Really? They don't provide any sources. Oh well.

Answer (score 6):

`std::array` cannot use an allocator; however, it seems like your SecureArray class can achieve what you want through a custom constructor/deconstructor.

Something like this:

```
#include <sys/mman.h>

template<class T, std::size_t Size>
struct SecureArray : public std::array<T, Size>
{
    // Your static_asserts...

    SecureArray(void) {
        mlock(std::array<T, Size>::data(), sizeof(T) * Size);
    }

    ~SecureArray(void) {
        char *bytes = reinterpret_cast<char *>(std::array<T, Size>::data());
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(T) * Size; i++)
            bytes[i] = 0;
        munlock(bytes, sizeof(T) * N);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 5):

> I know `std::array` is completely allocated in the stack

This is not quite true. `std::array` doesn't allocate any memory, so it depends on where you allocate it.

```
auto* arr = new std::array<int, 100>(); // BUM! it is allocated on the heap
```

> But this obviously lacks memory locking and complicates the performance scheme of `std::array` that is to be gained by using `std::array` in the first place.

Firstly, it is not a problem to lock memory on the stack. See POSIX example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <array>

int main()
{
    std::array<int, 3> a = {1, 2, 3};        // std::array allocated on the stack
    if (mlock(a.data(), sizeof(a)) == 0)
    {
        std::cout << "LOCKED" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

So, you can just call `mlock` or any portable analog in `SecureArray` constructor.

Secondly, what performance gain do you expect to get? Memory reading/writing speed doesn't depend on where you allocate your array, on the heap or on the stack. So, it is all about how fast you can allocate and lock the memory. If performance is critical, memory locking may be too slow (or not, who knows?) to call it every time in `SecureArray` constructor even if memory is allocated on the stack.

So, it is more handy to use `std::vector` with custom allocator. It may preallocate and prelock big memory chunks, so allocation speed will be almost as fast as on the stack.

Comment: This isn't about speed at all, it's about security and making sure that things are not moved, as moving generally means copying.

Comment: @Maarten-reinstateMonica hmm... it seems I didn't get the intention of using `std::array` instead of `std::vector` in first place. I thought it is about allocation speed.